# How to filter large no of nested documents in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have nested documents in an elasticsearch index

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Events": [
            {
                "EventTime": "2021-04-13T08:00:00.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "EventTime": "2021-04-13T08:10:00.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Events": [
            {
                "EventTime": "2021-04-13T09:00:00.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "EventTime": "2021-04-13T09:10:00.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Events": [
            {
                "EventTime": "2021-04-13T10:00:00.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "EventTime": "2021-04-13T10:10:00.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get all the documents with `EventTime < some given time`. I want to filter nested documents as well. So, I know we can do it using `inner_hits` as follows

```
{
  "_source": [ "Id" ],
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Events",
      "query": {
        "range": {
            "Events.EventTime": {
                "lte": "2021-04-13T09:20:00.000000Z"
            }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But we can only get at max 100 documents in `inner_hits`. If I have more that 100 nested documents, I can't use `inner_hits` without changing some configuration in elasticsearch. Is there a way to achieve this without changing the config?

Answer (score 0):

There's an explicit setting governing this and it's called [`max_inner_result_window`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings). You can increase it by running

```json
PUT your-index/_settings
{
  "index.max_inner_result_window": 10000
}
```

This setting is non-breaking because it doesn't require index dropping or reindexing.

There's no alternative to get around this inner hits limitation.